# jmeter Response code: 500 Response message: Internal Server Error Response headers:

Tags: java, jmeter, cookiemanager

I am running jmeter and encounter this problem, i have tried cookie manager and header manager, cache manager there, the problem is still there.

**POST data:**

```
store_id=34926840&country_code=SE&amount=2.00&merchant_reference=1487698674350&bank_name=Forex+Bank&payment_reference=DHUDYTHMMTV&internal_reference=185524&currency_code=SEK&status=PENDING
```

**Cookie Data:**

```
JSESSIONID=A5A4905F9FBDF18DC47A376F0226A388; AWSELB=B5FF67AD1CFA5460C8C7E086624D3BB9CE4C254E9C05CAED2F8B4C138D77F2FB3E8E2D91BE28957E695EB58D84B77AABC0950A0B63FB43504A613D484F319EB551578DB7CB
```

**Request Headers:**

```
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: https://qa.instantinternetbanking.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://qa.instantinternetbanking.com/internetbanking/webPASubmitData.form
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Length: 188
```

Comment: Have you checked the server's log? If it answers a 500, there must be an error logged.

Comment: Error 500 is a server side error. So its reason will depend on your app. But generally servers rarely respond with error 500 deliberately, so most likely you have found a bug.

Comment: Agree with previous responders - check your server, and bug your devs with it.

Although I have to mention that what you shown there looks like a GET querystring, not usual POST, where parameters/data are sent in the request body.

But even in case you've done something wrong on your side - the server response must be crystal clear, stating the cause of the problem (at least, possibly suggestion how to fix as well) instead of dropping generic 500 on client's head. So - it's a bug on server anyway!

Answer (score 1):

- [Server Error 5xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6)

  > The 5xx (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server
  > is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the
  > requested method...
- [500 Internal Server Error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1)

  > The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server
  > encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling
  > the request.

So I can see 2 possible explanations:

1. Issue with your server, execute the same request manually using browser to see of it is the case.
2. Issue with your request. When it comes to more or less complex web applications testing you cannot just record and replay the test, you need to keep in mind that there could be some mandatory dynamic parameters which need to be handled (the process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)) or some actions are not repeatable (for instance if transaction with reference number `DHUDYTHMMTV` is already finished you cannot send it once again, you will need a new one), etc.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, your method of troubleshooting is useful. I found it is correlation caused that  tokens need passed to next few steps. And most difficult thing is there are more one tokens which i figure out until check source codes.